# Need help eliminating Null data and retrieving last months records

Tags: sql, oracle, date, null, oracle12c

```
SELECT 
    CLIENTS.LAST_NAME, 
    CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME, 
    CLIENTS.DOB, 
    CLIENTS.ALT_ID,
    CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.SCREEN_DATE,
    CASE 
       WHEN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME = 'Patient Health Questionnaire (PHQ-9)' 
          THEN 'D - Depression Screen'
       WHEN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME = 'Resident CAGE-AID Questionnaire' 
          THEN 'B - Substance Abuse Screen'
       ELSE 'NULL'
    END AS SERVICE
FROM
    CLIENTS
JOIN 
    CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS ON CLIENTS.SHISID = CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.SHISID
WHERE  
    CLIENTS.LAST_NAME != 'TEST' 
    AND CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME != 'NULL'
```

I feel like I am pretty close on this one, but my where statement isn't working correctly. My service column is still populating the NULL data. The other part that I need help with is pulling just last months data. If you look at the image, the date format is 2020-03-14 17:38:00.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amieT.png)

Let me know if have any tips on my formatting, this is new to me.

Current code:

```
SELECT CLIENTS.LAST_NAME, 
   CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME, 
   CLIENTS.DOB, 
   CLIENTS.ALT_ID,
   CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.SCREEN_DATE,
   CASE 
        WHEN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME = 'Patient Health Questionnaire (PHQ-9)' THEN 'D - Depression Screen'
        WHEN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME = 'Resident CAGE-AID Questionnaire' THEN 'B - Substance Abuse Screen'
        ELSE CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME
    END AS SERVICE
FROM CLIENTS
JOIN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS
ON CLIENTS.SHISID = CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.SHISID
WHERE CLIENTS.LAST_NAME != 'TEST' 
AND CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME IN
(
'Patient Health Questionnaire (PHQ-9)',
'Resident CAGE-AID Questionnaire'
)
AND SCREEN_DATE 
BETWEEN
 add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) 
AND last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))
```

This is before the last month code:
[image]

This is after the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple requirements in your question, let me address one-by-one.

> CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME != 'NULL'

This is incorrect, `NULL` is not a string to compare using `!=` operator. The correct way is to use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
WHERE CLIENTS.LAST_NAME != 'TEST' 
AND CLIENTS.LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

> the date format is 2020-03-14 17:38:00

`DATE` doesn't have any format. What you see is the way it is displayed as per your `locale-specific NLS settings`.

You have coded your `CASE` expression to have `NULL` value as string in the `ELSE` part:

```
CASE 
   WHEN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME = 'Patient Health Questionnaire (PHQ-9)' 
      THEN 'D - Depression Screen'
   WHEN CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME = 'Resident CAGE-AID Questionnaire' 
      THEN 'B - Substance Abuse Screen'
   ELSE 'NULL' --> This is why you see NULL in your output
END AS SERVICE
```

Whenever the `THEN` expression is not met, it will display `'NULL'` as string.

Instead, you could simply make your filter condition as:

```
AND CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME IN
( 
  'Patient Health Questionnaire (PHQ-9)' , 
  'Resident CAGE-AID Questionnaire'
)
```

> The other part that I need help with is pulling just last months data

To get `LAST MONTH` data, you could use below condition:

```
AND SCREEN_DATE 
BETWEEN
    add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) 
AND last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))
```

For example,

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
SELECT
    add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), - 1) "start",
    last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), - 1)) "end"
FROM
    dual;

start      end       
---------- ----------
2020-04-01 2020-04-30
```

Comment: I just tried that solution and I am still getting the NULL results.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 Then use `IS NOT NULL` for the other column as well. See the edited answer.

Comment: @Latit Kumar B - This brings me back to square one, where the 'Test' records have been removed , but I am still getting 'NULL' records in my Service column.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 It is your `CASE` expression that is causing the NULL values as string. See edited answer.

Comment: @Latit Kumar B - I am trying to figure out a way to get you my table without compromising the data in it. This has clients information in it..any suggestions?

Comment: @Latit Kumar B - When I remove the 'ELSE' from the 'CASE', I and still getting a NULL Service. This is because those Services are not Patient Health Questionnaire (PHQ-P) or Resident CAGE_AID Questionnaire.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 No, if you remove `ELSE` then it will actually become `NULL`. Instead you do, `ELSE CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS.TEST_NAME`. Also, remember, `'NULL'` and `NULL` are not same. The former is a string, while the latter means nothing. Unfortunately in Oracle, it's an empty string.

Comment: @Latit Kumar B - Hey, that works!! And makes a lot more sense to me. Now I just need to figure out how to parse out last months data.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 See my edited answer for `last month` data.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 If you see less rows than your expect, it simply means even your `SCREEN_DATE ` column has NULL values. You have data issues which you need to address in your table design. If you don't want NULL at all, then you should add a `NOT NULL constraint` on those columns first.

Comment: @Latit Kumar B -I added some pictures of my table. It looks like it is deleting most of the clients that completed both services. Either that or it doesn't like when the SCREEN_DATE has the same timestamp.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 Okay, in that case you need to figure out and fix your data issues.

Comment: @Latit Kumar B - Actually it is eliminating the records from the last day of the month.

Comment: You know that's impossible unless something either wrong with the data or the logic in the SQL. So, I will need your data, table DDL and desired output to help further.

Comment: How can I get that to you? The tables have confidential information in them.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 Either obfuscate the data or post sample data as per your understanding, This is going too long for answering a post, but given that you are new here I am helping.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added my code along with before and after tables to my original post. Does this help you? And thank you for all of your help, you have been incredibly helpful!

Comment: I used this code and got the results that I wanted 'AND SCREEN_DATE 
BETWEEN
    add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) 
AND TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1,-1))' ------I'm not really sure how to add the code in the correct format in here.

Comment: @latitkumbarb I just realized been spelling your name wrong this whole time, I am sorry for that.